# Как собрать проект со всеми необходимыми библиотеками?

Tags: c++

Всем привет,в общем,я написал свой софт и продаю его.Но у большинства возникают проблемы,программа требует vcruntime140.dll.Можно ли как нибудь прикомпилировать ее к проекту или сделать чтоб программа не требовала никакие внешние библиотеки?Почему вообще программа на с++ требует какие то внешние библиотеки?Как это исправить?Устал каждому просто говорить скачивать все версии visual c++.Почему тогда другие программы у них не требуют эту библиотеку?

Comment: ниже вам дали развернутый верный ответ, но вы его заминусовали.

Answer (score 2):

Я конечно удивлён что вы что то продаёте но при этом не знаете о рантайм либах но да ладно. Все эти либы идут вместе с инсталятором, самый простой вариант это тупо класть их рядом со своим софтом в инсталяторе. Более сложный это определять установлен ли необходимый vc runtime. Возможно вы встречали сообщение "Установить распространяемый компонент Microsoft Visual C++?" это вот оно.

Конкретных рекомендаций "Как собрать проект со всеми необходимыми библиотеками", дать сложно, всё зависит от конкретно вашего цикла CI/CD.